# How to get renovate to update the java version in my pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom, renovate

I want renovate to keep my Java versions in my pom.xml updated.
I had a look on the information in the renovate docs and it seems like it should work out of the box:
https://docs.renovatebot.com/java/#lts-releases 
https://docs.renovatebot.com/presets-workarounds/#workaroundsjavaltsversions

My renovate config looks like this:

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackageNames": [
        "maven-wrapper"
      ],
      "enabled": false
    }
  ],
  "configMigration": true,
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended",
    "group:allNonMajor",
    ":approveMajorUpdates"
  ]
}
```

And my pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.70.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-service</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>eclipse-temurin:${java.version}-alpine</image>  <----
                    </from>
                    ....
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm overwriting the Java version that the Spring Boot Starter Parent uses with `<java.version>17</java.version>`, I also use this to determine the version of the eclipse Temurin base image in JIB.

Renovate won't pick up this dependency/version.
What am I doing wrong? There also are no related logs in the debug output.

**Update:**
Thanks to @Gaël J I created a [feature request](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/27645) in the renovate project.

Answer (score 0):

*As of 2024-02, this is not yet supported but you can submit a feature request or even a pull request in Renovate's GitHub*

---

The [`java` datasource](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/datasource/java-version/) available in Renovate is only supported by the [`asdf` manager](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/asdf/#supported-datasources).

The [`maven` manager](https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/manager/maven/) does not use the `java` datasource to detect and suggest updates of `java.version` Maven property.

Comment: how is renovate doing the java upgrade here then? :)
https://docs.renovatebot.com/java/

Comment: This page is confusing but it doesn't state that Java version upgrades are supported in Maven (or Gradle). It's a high level page about Java ecosystem with unrelated sections.

Comment: Thanks, yeah the page in combination with the Maven and Gradle configs below is a bit misleading. :)  I created a feature request for adding support for the java datasource to the maven manager. https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/27645